# apply and which function require operator error

Tags: r, apply

I have a reference table :

```
ref <- data.frame("Strong"=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D"),
              "Medium"=c("A","B","B","C","C","D","D"),
              "Moderate"=c("B","C","C","C","D","D","D"),
              "Weak"=c("C","C","D","D","D","D","D"))
rownames(ref) <- c("WS1","WS2","WS3","WS4","WS5","WS6","WS7")
```

And a large `dataframe` (sample here-under):

```
df <- data.frame("Rad"=c("Weak","Weak","Weak","Moderate","Moderate"), "Wind"=c("WS4","WS3","WS3","WS2","WS4"))
```

I need to look up the `Wind`and `Rad`values from `df`in my reference table `ref`. To do so, I use the following code to retrieve the Index and then I would use those index values to copy the value from `ref`:

```
df$x <- apply(df,1,function(x){which(colnames(ref) == df[x,"Rad"])})
df$x <- apply(df,1,function(x){which(colnames(ref) == x$Rad)})

df$y <- apply(df,1,function(x){which(rownames(ref) == df[x,"Wind"])})
df$y <- apply(df,1,function(x){which(rownames(ref) == x$Wind)})
```

The expected output looks like this:

```
   Rad     Wind  PG
 1 Weak     WS4  D
 2 Weak     WS3  D
 3 Weak     WS3  D
 4 Moderate WS2  C
 5 Moderate WS4  C
```

The code above works, but there are issues:

- I shouldn't have to write the lines "twice", but the code won't run if I run only the 2nd one.
- The first line doesn't do what it's expected (and it shouldn't since the syntax is wrong) but, again, the 2nd line won't run if I do not use the "failed" one first
- Lastly, although this works, I am pretty sure there are other, easier, ways to do what I'm doing. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: yes it should. I manually edited the sample to have it use different columns and forgot to change that line. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `match` `rownames` and `colnames` of `ref` with `RAD` and `WIND` column respectively and subset from `ref`.

```
df$PG <- ref[cbind(match(df$Wind, rownames(ref)), match(df$Rad, colnames(ref)))]
df

#       Rad Wind PG
#1     Weak  WS4  D
#2     Weak  WS3  D
#3     Weak  WS3  D
#4 Moderate  WS2  C
#5 Moderate  WS4  C
```

Comment: I had never used the `match` function; that would have saved me so much time! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

An other approach using `data.table`. Shuld run fast, even on large data-sets.
Uses the same logic as the solution by @IceCreamToucan, but stays within `data.table`.

explained: uses a molten `ref`-table, to perform an update join on `df`.

```
library( data.table )

setDT(df)[ melt( setDT( ref, keep.rownames = TRUE ), id.vars = "rn" ), 
           PG := i.value, 
           on = .( Wind == rn, Rad == variable )][]

#         Rad Wind PG
# 1:     Weak  WS4  D
# 2:     Weak  WS3  D
# 3:     Weak  WS3  D
# 4: Moderate  WS2  C
# 5: Moderate  WS4  C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table) # for melt

ref_long <- 
  ref %>% 
    rownames_to_column('row') %>% 
    melt('row')

df %>% 
  left_join(ref_long, by = c('Rad' = 'variable', 'Wind' = 'row'))

#        Rad Wind value
# 1     Weak  WS4     D
# 2     Weak  WS3     D
# 3     Weak  WS3     D
# 4 Moderate  WS2     C
# 5 Moderate  WS4     C
```

Comment: If you are already loading `tidyverse` why not use `gather` ?

Comment: Honestly that function just confuses me. It seems Rstudio has acknowledged spread/gather are a little confusing since they're soon to be replaced by pivot_wide and pivot_long currently in the dev version. I would've used those if they weren't in dev but personally the way gather works doesn't make much sense to me and seems to make things harder to read than melt, which appears simpler to my eye since it works with only one argument.

Comment: yes, makes sense. I know about the replacement functions was not sure about your preference behind it.